# Email intent back to activity

Tags: android, email, button, android-intent, back

Can anyone tell me how to redirect email intent's back button to activity where send mail button is present. I was succeeded to send mail from my android app by using email intent.But I want the flow to be exists only in my app without opening mail inbox. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the email from your app you will have to implement IMAP or SMTP protocols in your application. There may be some third-party libraries available already

And if you're asking about behavior of the GMail app after it proceeds your intent, you can't alter it

Comment: thanks for ur answer..I am using email intent that enable the user to type their message now I want the composer sheet back button returns to my activity rather than opening inbox

Comment: That is not possible. It's up to that email activity to define what happens when user clicks the back button

Comment: what about startActivityForResult?

Comment: startActivityForResult won't work, unfortunately (meaning that it won't return a result **after** sending, but **before** - so you can't pop up a message saying "eMail sent").

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible for that you have to build the Php backend(webservice) for sending email, in that you can put subject,recipient address and message with that webservice.

Comment: I am using android email intent for sending mail not php service files

Comment: so without php backend you cant do that you want.

Comment: Actually I want the UI that user has to enter their message,subject...For sending email it's not problem