# Going BACK to app after email intent brings you to email client

Tags: android, android-intent

So I'm able to get my email intent working. I have a button that I press and it allows me to choose my email client and then it takes me to the client I press.

My problem though is when I press my smartphone's "back" button, it either takes me back to the main feed of my email client or back to the home screen of my phone...

How do I get it to go back to my actual app? Preferably where it was right before it went to the email client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake, you aren't supposed call the method finish() in your onAttach function...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Check this answer: [Email intent back to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679341/email-intent-back-to-activity)

You might want to implement an IMAP Protocol in your app in order to send the email inside the app without needing for an intent to open an email sharing app.

This will help you build your own email sending in your app using JavaMail API
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)